# URL function in vue3

Tags: url, vuejs3

```
tempString = '@public/static/img/ZY3_2m.png';
let tempUrl = new URL("@public/static/img/ZY3_2m.png", import.meta.url); // working
let tempUrl = new URL(tempString, import.meta.url); // not working
console.log(tempUrl);
return tempUrl.href;
```

Why is passing a string different from passing a variable to the URL function?

Comment: You should define what "not working means". If you get an error message please post it. Also does the error say "tempUrl already defined"?

Comment: thank you for your reply,  if tempUrl.href value is http://172.18.0.170:3000/static/img/ZY3_2m.png（working）. and http://172.18.0.170:3000/src/components/@public/static/img/ZY3_2m.png(not working)

Comment: I aliased @public to the public directory

Comment: I want to dynamically generate the correct url.

Comment: That wasn't really what I asked you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement is done by Vite, in the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url), it says:

> the URL string must be static so it can be analyzed, otherwise the code will be left as is

and as an example:

```
// Vite will not transform this
const imgUrl = new URL(imagePath, import.meta.url).href
```

This is exactly what happens in your case, where Vite cannot analyze `tempString` in `new URL(tempString, import.meta.url)`, and you end up with the unresolved alias in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

It's a broken image due to the way Vite replaces variables during asset handling. The string variable's value gets replaced by Vite as being relative to `/src`, so the resulting href value would be `/src/@public/static/img/ZY3_2m.png` which is obviously not correct and results in a broken image.

Vite assumes if you're importing an asset that it's going to be from `/src`, because **assets from `/public` don't need to be imported**

For example, if you have an asset path `/public/static/img/ZY3_2m.png`, you can directly set it as the image source and Vite will assume it's path as being relative to `/public`

```html
<img src="/static/img/ZY3_2m.png">
```

[Stackblitz examples](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-ba4br4?file=vite.config.js,src%2FApp.vue)